# SWRevealController with localization (Right to Left), Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, swrevealviewcontroller

I recently used SWRevealController for IOS and it worked fine, but when i tried to test localization for Right to Left languages, the rear view still slides from Left, it should do from Right, is there any way to call sw_right segue instead of sw_rear in case of right-to-left localization?

specially in SWRevealController we are not calling segues by identifier, any ideas?

Comment: if `SWRevealController` isn't doing it automatically and doesn't provide a way to trigger segues by identifiers, may write this feature in and send a Pull Request? If you'd consider doing it, there's a number of resources available e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551909/specify-direction-of-show-push-segue , I might be interested in this too if you go for it, let me know and we can probably work together on this.

Comment: am still new to swift and it sounds a big task to me :)

Comment: @MohammedTurky Have you got any solution?